# Issue with Input Device Selection in Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS

Tags: microphone, headphones

I am a new Ubuntu user and have been using Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS as my operating system. First and foremost, I would like to express my gratitude for the exceptional work you have done in creating such a powerful and user-friendly OS.

However, I have encountered a particular issue regarding the selection of input devices in the sound settings. I have a pair of headphones with a broken microphone, and when I attempt to change the input device, the only option available is "Microphone-Built-in-audio." Unfortunately, this option only works when the headphones are connected.

When I unplug the headphones, I am presented with the option "Internal Microphone-Built-in-audio," which works perfectly. However, it would be incredibly beneficial if I could have both options available simultaneously, regardless of whether the headphones are connected or not.

I have tried various software solutions, including PulseAudio Volume Control, ALSA Mixer, and pavucontrol, in an attempt to address this issue. Unfortunately, despite my efforts, the problem persists.

I kindly request your assistance in resolving this matter. It would be greatly appreciated if this issue could be addressed and resolved in the next Ubuntu update. Having the ability to select between the two options, even with the headphones connected, would significantly enhance the usability and flexibility of Ubuntu.

Thank you for your attention to this matter, and for your dedication to improving Ubuntu. I look forward to your response and any guidance you can provide.